# How do I disable different views for the party list field in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-365

I have created a custom activity type entity, and on this entity form, I've placed a OOB party list lookup field.

As of now, many views are available for the selection of records in this lookup. But I want only one view to be visible for the selection.

I tried different ways to disable the unwanted views, but I didn't find a suitable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with javaScript. Look here if this might be of help:
https://community.dynamics.com/blogs/post/?postid=c384bd1a-1642-450a-989e-509b37550d2a

Best regards,
Luka